# How can I set the viewport size of PhantomJS through grunt & jasmine?

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm trying to test something using grunt + jasmine + phantomjs. This specific test requires a large viewport so the responsive styles render the large-screen version within phantomjs.

I noticed in the `grunt-contrib-jasmine` plugin this code, which would seem to allow for setting phantomjs options:

```
// Merge task-specific options with these defaults.
var options = this.options({
  ...
  phantomjs : {},
  ...
});
```

However, when I add this to my config in grunt it has no effect:

```
options: {
  phantomjs: {
    viewportSize: {
      width: 2000,
      height: 1000
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in the fact that `viewportSize` is an option for the `page` object, not phantomjs. The grunt config needs to look like this:

```
taskName: {
  options: {
    page: {
      viewportSize: {
        width: 2000,
        height: 800
      }
    },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the `viewportSize` after the page is loaded? [Docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) say this is for 'the preferred initial size' but I'd like to resize it during a test to check some responsive behavior.