# Testing window.matchMedia with phantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, media-queries, phantomjs

I wrote some JavaScript logic with AngularJS to match bootstrap media-queries inside javascript for more complex responsive use-cases. Which is working fine, albeit a little bit ugly:

```
var xs = window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width : 767px)');
xs.addListener(function(mq) {
            console.log('resize xs');
            if (mq.matches) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    service.screenSize = 'xs';
                }, 0);
            }
        });
```

However, when trying to unit test this behaviour using karma, jasmine & phantomJS - i can't find a way to resize the actual window. When resizing innerWidth for example, it resizes, but it doesn't trigger the mediaquery as it - i presume -  looks at the window, not at the innerWidth.

Anyone have a clue how to address this issue?

Comment: This may be helpful: [How can I set the viewport size of PhantomJS through grunt & jasmine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613709/how-can-i-set-the-viewport-size-of-phantomjs-through-grunt-jasmine) I don't know if this is applicable to your case